# Error.String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s (While Sending Email For Account Verification in MVC4 C#)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, c#-4.0, email-verification

I am doing an MVC application and trying to send an email to registered user for his account activation and email account verification.
Its working Fine on LocalHost but when i Deployed it on live server it gave me this error:

**Error.String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s**
Following is the Code which i have written for sending email:

```
 var verifyUrl = string.Empty;
                verifyUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/Account/AccountVerify?I=" + NewUserID;

            string body = "<html><head><meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /></head><body><p>Dear " + objuserdet.Email + "" +
                        ", </p><p>To verify your account, please click the following link:</p>"
                        + "<p><a href=\"" + verifyUrl + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + verifyUrl + ""
                        + "</a></p><div>Best regards,</div><div>" + NewUserID + " Team.</div><p>Note: Do not forward "
                        + "this email. The verify link is private.</p></body></html>";
            string To = objuserdet.Email;
            string Subject = "Account Activation";

            SendEmail(To,Subject,body);
```

and here is the Email Method:

```
public void SendEmail(string To, string Subject, string Body)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
               // mail.From = new MailAddress(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailID"].ToString());
                mail.From = new MailAddress("blue.naina9@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add(To.Trim());
                mail.Subject = Subject.Trim();
                mail.Body = Body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            System.Net.NetworkCredential BasicAuthenticationInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("blue.naina9@gmail.com","*******");
            smtp.Timeout = 600000;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = BasicAuthenticationInfo;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

..

Any Help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Since it only throwing exception in deployment machine, can you provide stack trace of the error? Seems that a certain method which expects a string value parameter `s` e.g. `DateTime.Parse` is assigned to null value during deployment.

Comment: thanks for responding @TetsuyaYamamoto Yamamoto..I got it resolved..The Issue was not in code basically on localhost i was sending mail from email account registered from my current location but on deployment server location shifted to US so gmail blocks the mail due to location change and dint allow the sender to login through application..I US account for sending email and then its working Fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Error Occurs because Gmail blocks Sign-in Request of Sender Email Account From my Application due to change in my current location and Deployment server location(that is in US).
So i added a US based Account for Sending Email and it stats working Fine For me..
Hope this Help Others As well..

Answer (score 1):

Posting stack trace would have helped. How ever the only place I think this kind of error will come is

```
mail.To.Add(To.Trim());
```

replace `string To = objuserdet.Email;`

with

```
 if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objuserdet.Email)){
   string To = objuserdet.Email;
 }
 else{
   throw new Exception("Email is null!");
 }
```

Check if this works!

Comment: Well thanks for responding @Shahbaaz..I got it resolved..The Issue was not in code basically on localhost i was sending mail from email account registered from my current location but on deployment server location shifted to US so gmail blocks the mail due to location change and dint allow the sender to login through application..I US account for sending email and then its working Fine...